# TypeError when running jasmine specs that use a jQuery plugin built using the Widget factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [toggleEdit](http://alz.so/toggleedit/) for inline editing.

Everything works fine when the code is actually used in the page.

However, my test suite fails with the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined`

I tracked it down to be triggered from within the `clear` method of this particular plugin. Its source file can be found [here](http://alz.so/static/plugins/toggleedit/jquery.toggleedit.js).

There are two relevant bits in that code:

1- The `_init` function

```
self.element.addClass("toggleEdit toggleEdit-edit toggleEdit-edit-" +   
self._tag(self.element))
//store reference to preview element
.data("toggleEdit-preview", self.p);
```

As you can see, when the plugin is first instantiated it uses the `data` structure on `self` to store the newly created element.

2- The `clear` function

```
self.element.data("toggleEdit-preview").remove();
```

The `clear` function then tries to access that structure and retrieve the element. That's when, while inside a jasmine spec, it fails with the aforementioned exception.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

EDIT:

This is my spec, it's the simplest piece of code able to reproduce the error:

```
it("should update the given attribute on the server", function(){
  $('#user-details input, #user-details select').toggleEdit(); //this line triggers the error
});
```

http://alz.so/static/plugins/toggleedit/jquery.toggleedit.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem: old version of the jQuery + jQuery UI duo. Upgrading them resolves the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was taking a look at the source for toggleEdit and it seems that the only 2 times the function clear is called is just before self.element.data gets set:

```
if (typeof self.element.data("toggleEdit-preview") !== "undefined") {
     self.clear();
     self.disableEvents();
}
```

And at destroy function:

```
destroy: function() {
         var self = this;
         self.clear();
         self.disableEvents();
         $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(self, arguments);
       }
```

Since the first call seems to be protected, I ask you a somewhat dumb question: Is it possible that destroy is being called twice?

Comment: It's not being called twice according to my tests. And that's what bugs me. Destroy is called by jQuery following the widget factory protocol, but it seems to be referring to a different `this` when it gets called.